# Passing the inputs of two variables to an array and into the constructor in the reference class and printing them

Tags: java, arrays, class, reference

I'm having a hard time passing the inputs of two variables into an array and passing the values of the array in the constructor of a reference class. I can provide more code if necessary. Your help is deeply appreciated!

Currently, this is where I'm at:

```java
System.out.print("No. of subjects to enroll: ");
choice = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("-------------------------------");
String code;
int grade;
String[] codeArray = new String[choice];
int[] gradeArray = new int[choice];
for (int x = 0; x < codeArray.length; x++) {
    System.out.print("Code of the subject " + (x + 1) + ": ");
    code = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("What's the grade for " + code + ": ");
    grade = keyboard.nextInt();
    codeArray[x] = code;
    gradeArray[x] = grade;

    int s = 0;
    while (s < codeArray.length) {
        // StudentGrades is the constructor where I am passing the input.
        sg = new StudentGrades(codeArray[s], gradeArray[s]);
        s++;
    }
}
```

This is the part where I am getting the passed inputs through the getter methods.

```java
int i = 0;
System.out.printf("%-5s %15s %n", "Course Code: ", "Grades: ");
while (i < codeArray.length) {
    System.out.printf("%-5s %20s %n", sg.getCourseCode(), sg.getGrade());
    i++;
}
```

This is the constructor of the StudentGrades() reference class:

```java
public StudentGrades(String courseCode, int grade) {
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

Here's a sample output that I get. As you can see, it only prints the it412 subject code. I tried using the param 0 in replacement of the S but it displays the it411 only also.

```
No. of subjects to enroll: 2
-------------------------------
Code of the subject 1: it411
What's the grade for it411: 90
Code of the subject 2: it412
What's the grade for it412: 91
Course Code:         Grades:  
it412                   91 
it412                   91 
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks like `sg` is re-assigned on each iteration, so after the loop `sg` will contain the last assigned value.  Then the next loop iterates again, displaying `sg`.

Comment: @AndrewS I tried putting the sg outside of the loop but it still shows the same output.

Comment: There is only a single `sg` so it will always be the same value after the first loop ends.  Try moving the `System.out.printf` to the other loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If StudentGrades represent 1 StudentGrade (you should rename it if that's the intent) then you need to keep a list of the Student Grades as you create them.

Replace this code:

```
while (s < codeArray.length ) {
  sg = new StudentGrades(codeArray[s], gradeArray[s]);
  ...
```

With something like:

```
List<StudentGrades> studentGrades = new ArrayList<>();
while (s < codeArray.length ) {
  sg = new StudentGrades(codeArray[s], gradeArray[s]);
  studentGrades.add(sg);
  ...
```

Comment: Tried it on the code and it works. Thanks for the help!